Replacing LED lamps with different Lumens
I need to replace an LED lamp. On the lamp I see:
400lm 6W 67lm/W 32mA
I have some lamps in storage that say: 345 Lumen/4.7Watt = 50Watt
If I understand correctly I could replace the lamp with the one from storage and the only difference is that it is less luminous?
Does it matter if I have 2 LED lamps from the storage and 1 LED lamp like the original one in the same fixture?

That’ll be fine, assuming you have the right bases.
The only other thing to consider is that they might be a different color temperature (2700K - 6000K) that might be visually jarring if set beside each other.
